# Login in with myopenid

Tags: support

I've used myopenid for login in to the stack exchange sites, but is going to get closed soon. It seems to be already at low maintenance mode, and barely works. How can I change the way I log?

I've tried the "Add more logins" - "Login with Stack Exchange" option, but it fails with an absurd "Email already in use." Of course it's in use.

How do I migrate from myopenid?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account

Comment: Thanks, sadly, it doesn't work for me, as I intend to use the same email for my log in.

Comment: Then use the contact form as instructed.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, here's what I have done to correct the myopenid problem, I hope it works for anyone using myopenid:

- Try to login, then go to "click here to recover your account"
- It will send you the typical email as if you had lost the password. Be patient, it can take a few minutes.
- The recovery url will get you to the correct form where you can set an user name and a password even if your email is already in the system.

Now you can enter to the system with an stack overflow powered openid (first big icon at the login page) instead of myopenid.